# Why does sympy.nonlinsolve not solve this nonlinear equation?

Tags: python, sympy, exponential

I have an equation. I need to make `v1` as the subject and derive a value.

This is my equation:
`fp1*(sp.exp(39.44*v1/n1))*(1-(sp.exp(-39.44*v1)))-Ival[0]=0` where `fp1,n1` are parameters where we have values for them and we pass values to `Ival[0]` and need to take a value to `v1`. How can I do this?

I used the `nonlinsolve` function and it doesn't solve the function rather gives the same equation. I need a numerical value to `v1`.

here are my `Ival[0]` values:

```
-6.03e-07, -4.32e-07, -2.93e-07, -1.96e-07, -1.07e-07, 1e-20, 5.4e-07, 1.43e-06, 2.26e-06, 2.93e-06, 3.44e-06
```

Passing these values I need to take values to `v1.`
values for parameters:

```
fp1=2.75479*10**-6

n1=-32.9513
```

code:

```
 from sympy import symbols, nonlinsolve
 import sympy as sp
 v1= symbols('v1', real=True)
    nonlinsolve([fp1*(sp.exp(39.44*v1/n1))*(1-(sp.exp(-39.44*v1)))-Ival[0]], [v1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the floating numerical values (and highly nonlinear nature of the function) I would recommend using `nsolve`. And to help it be better posed, giving a value near order 1 in the vicinity of the root, I would recommend dividing by fp1:

```py
>>> eq = (sp.exp(39.44*v1/n1))*(1-(sp.exp(-39.44*v1)))-i/fp1
```

Then loop over `i` values in `Ival = [-6.03e-07, -4.32e-07, ...]` using the last known solution as the initial guess for the next solution:

```py
>>> guess = 0
>>> for i in Ival:
...     eq = (sp.exp(39.44*v1/n1))*(1-(sp.exp(-39.44*v1)))-i/fp1
...     guess = nsolve(eq, guess)
...     print(ival, guess)
```

It will be worth your time to think about where you expect to find roots and adjust the initial guess accordingly. You will get an error when `nsolve` can no longer find a solution near the guess. Try using a [graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) to see what the function looks like.